# Using amsmath \text in subscript rasterized / pixelates subscript

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, text

I'm confused about the output of the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{standalone} % required
\pagestyle{empty} % required
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\( D_\text{pz} \)

\end{document}
```

The resulting subscript is rasterized / pixelated. When using `\mathrm` this doesn't happen. Why does it happen with `\text`, is there a way to fix this or should i use `\mathrm` anyway?

Comment: install the cm-super package with the package manager of your tex system. But beside this: yes you should use \mathrm and always use braces around the whole subscript. `\D_ {\mathrm{pz}}`

Comment: if you want to know why `\text` is the wrong macro to use: `\textit{ \( D_{\text{pz}} \)}`, now `pz` is italic, not what you wanted. This misuse of `\text` is sadly very very common these days. Out of curiosity, from where do you have that `\text should be a good macro to do this?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if you can explain why `cm-super` is needed (and what it does), and why `mathrm` is prefered, I'd be happy to accept this as an answer.

Comment: You are presumably using MikTeX. Miktex uses a bitmap font as the default font, thus it may look pixalated. TeXLive on the other hand uses `cm-super` (which takes up some space) but is an outline/vector font. By installing `cm-super` in miktex, you make this vectorfont the default font in miktex. I already explained above why `\text` is bad. You want the `pz` to be upright in all contexts, `\text` is not.